# Regex with positive lookbehind that will match multiple lines

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm struggling with regex that will match multiple lines after some specific string.

Let's say we have a sample data like:

```
Data1
some changing text
12406943 Old Company New Company reason Something 1/2/2005 10,00
14757152 Old Company 2 New Company 2 Reason 2 Something2 10/7/2007 8,00

Data2
some changing text
12406943 New Company invoice1 31.01.2005 500,00
14757152 New Company 2 invoice2 28.05.2007 1000,00
```

Earlier I was getting data from Data1 with regex:

```
(?<caseNumber>\d+) +?(?<temp>.*) +?(?>Something|Something2).*(?<originalDate>\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}) +?(?<interestRate>\d{1,3}\.\d{2}).*
```

and Data2:

```
(?<caseNumber>\d+) +?(?<companyName>.*) +?(?<invoiceNumber>\S*) +?\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}
```

Unfortunately something changed and the date format for Data1 is the same as for Data2 and regex for Data2 is getting rows from Data1.

```
Data1
some changing text
12406943 Old Company New Company reason Something 02.01.2005 10,00
14757152 Old Company 2 New Company 2 Reason 2 Something2 07.10.2007 8,00

Data2
some changing text
12406943 New Company invoice1 31.01.2005 500,00
14757152 New Company 2 invoice2 28.05.2007 1000,00
```

I wanted to use positive lookbehind and check if before all Data2 rows I will find Data2 text, but it only returns the first row from results

```
(?<=Data2\Rsome changing text\R)(?<caseNumber>\d+) +?(?<companyName>.*) +?(?<invoiceNumber>\S*) +?\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}
```

The use-case in java code is that I find the row by regex matcher `.find()` method and then call that method in a `while` loop to run row by row. In above situation it will only return one row and that's not what I want.

Do you maybe have any idea how to define that regex or enable any multiline searching for data row after some text?
Maybe that's some novice mistake, but I can't see it for now :)

If I tried to use quantifier, and treat the main data as group it takes the last occurrence only:

```
(?<=Data2\Rsome changing text\R)((?<caseNumber>\d+) +?(?<companyName>.*) +?(?<invoiceNumber>\S*) +?\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}.*\R)+
```

Comment: Can you share what you want to capture? No sample IO makes it hard for some users to understand what the problem is.

Comment: I think for this to work you'll need a lookbehind that included the data row pattern, not sure if it's possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, you can make use of the `\G` anchor instead of using a lookbehind assertion.

**Explanation**

```
(?:^Data2\Rsome changing text|\G(?!^))\R(?<caseNumber>\d+)\h+(?<companyName>\S.*?)\h+(?<invoiceNumber>\S+)\h+\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\b.*
```

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `^Data2\Rsome changing text` From the start of the string, match the text literally followed by newlines
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the current position at the end of the previous match, not at the start
- `)\R` Close non capture group and match a unicode newline sequence
- `(?<caseNumber>\d+)\h+` Capture 1+ digits and 1+ spaces
- `(?<companyName>\S.*?)\h+` Capture a single non whitespace char followed by any chars (as least as possible) and 1+ spaces
- `(?<invoiceNumber>\S+)\h+` Capture 1+ non whitespace chars and 1+ spaces
- `\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\b` Match a date like pattern in the data
- `.*` Match the rest of the line

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CHa0aE/1).

Comment: Wow, that's a great solution, I wasn't aware of `\G` anchor, but along with your explanation it all makes sense now.